# Checking if two Dasks are the same

Tags: dask

What is the right way to determine if two Dask objects refer to the same result? Is it as simple as comparing the `name` attributes of both or are there other checks that need to be run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of any of the dask collections in the main library (array, bag, delayed, dataframe) yes, equal names should imply equal values.

However the opposite is not always true.  We don't use deterministic hashing everywhere.  Sometimes we use uuid's instead.  For example, random arrays always get random UUIDs for keys, but two random arrays *might* be equal by chance.

No guarantees are given for collections made outside of the Dask library.  No enforcement is made at the scheduler level.

Comment: To be clear I was referring to value equality even if keys are different.  One can come by the same set of numbers in a variety of ways.  The hashing is defined by the path, not the final result.